# OBTENER FECHA Y SUMARLE 1 DIA - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Buen día para todos, por favor me podrían orientar sobre qué sucede en este problema?.

Básicamente lo que estoy intentado hacer es poner una fecha máxima a un DatePicker la cuál será 1 día más a la fecha de hoy; es decir mañana.

El problema es que si estamos en el día 31 de un mes, el máximo será "32". O en meses con sólo 30 días, estará mostrando "31" como día siguiente.

Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer que si es fin de mes lo detecte y me arroje el primer día del mes siguiente.

Es decir:
Hoy es 31 de diciembre del 2021, mañana será 01 de enero del 2022.
Agradezco mucho su ayuda. :)

```js
function fecha(){
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;

    $('[type="date"]').prop('max', function(){
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var ol = currentDate.getDate();
        days = 1;
        var fechs = currentDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (ol<10 ? 0 : '') + month + '-' + (ol<10 ? 0 : '') + (currentDate.getDate() + days);
     console.log(fechs);
      return fechs;
        });

var day = d.getDate();
window.output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    (month<10 ? 0 : '') + month + '-' +
    (day<10 ? 0 : '') + day;

$('[type="date"]').prop('min', function(){
     return output;
    });
console.log(output);

};
```

```css
input[type=date] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #0faad1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fecha();">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css?n=1">


    <label for="Fecha"><span style="color: red;">* </span>
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Fecha: <input type="date" id="fecha" value="Seleccione Fecha" name="Fecha" min="new Date();" max="2021-12-31" required data-msg="Ingrese la fecha a reservar.">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día! esto se puede solucionar de varias maneras, sin el uso de paquetes

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(date.addDays(1));
```

O utilizando paquetes como DayJs que facilitan la manipulación de fechas:

- Instalación de paquete: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs
- Método que vas a necesitar: https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/add

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const fechaFinAnio = new Date('2021/12/31');

/**
 * Funcion que reforna la fecha siguiente a la fecha pasada por parametro
 */
const fechaSiguiente = (f) => {
  return new Date(f.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
};

// Salida: Fecha del parametro, fecha siguiente
console.log(fechaFinAnio, fechaSiguiente(fechaFinAnio));

// Ejemplo 2
const fechaActual = new Date();
console.log(fechaActual, fechaSiguiente(fechaActual));

// Ejemplo 3
const fechaFinMesEnero = new Date('2022/01/31');
console.log(fechaFinMesEnero, fechaSiguiente(fechaFinMesEnero));
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el siguiente dia de la fecha actual puedes sumar `86 400 000` (la cantidad de milisegundos de  un dia) a la cantidad de milisegundos de la fecha actual:

```
//Obtiener la fecha actual
let actualDay = new Date();
//Le sumas 86 400 000 a los milisegundos actuales
let nextDay = new Date(actualDay.getMilliseconds() + 86400000);
```